# MySQL Inner Joint and multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am using two table named Transactions and Items. Refer below

**Table 1 : Transactions**

```
C_ID - State - Time
1   Start 2016-07-13 16:02:42
1   Passed  2016-07-13 20:28:21
2   Passed  2016-07-11 17:39:13
3   Passed  2016-07-07 20:23:00
4   Start   2016-07-01 13:19:54
4   Passed  2016-07-01 17:37:41
5   Start   2016-07-07 16:16:21
5   Passed  2016-07-07 21:04:01
6   Passed  2016-07-07 21:11:39
7   Passed  2016-07-08 20:30:46
```

**Table 2 : Items**

```
C_No - C_ID
C1 - 5
C2 - 3
C3 - 9
C4 - 7
C5 - 6
C6 - 8
C7 - 2
C8 - 4
C9 - 10
C10 - 1
```

I would like to join these tables and need output as mentioned below;

**Output**

```
C_No - State - Time
C10 - Start 2016-07-13 16:02:42
C10 - Passed    2016-07-13 20:28:21
C8 - Start  2016-07-01 13:19:54
C8 - Passed 2016-07-01 17:37:41
C1 - Start  2016-07-07 16:16:21
C1 - Passed 2016-07-07 20:00:01
```

In addition to join two tables, I want a filter on State and Time. The conditions are (State = 'Start' and Time <= 17:00) and (State = 'Passed' and Time <= 21:00)

I don't want any item doesn't have both Start and Passed.

I used the following query

```
{SELECT distinct(c.C_No), p.State, p.Time FROM Items c
inner join Transitions p on p.c_id = c.c_id  and date(p.Time) between '2016-07-01' and CURRENT_DATE() 
and ((p.State = 'Start' and time(p.Time) <= '17:00:00') or p.State = 'Passed' )
order by c.C_No, State;}
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f05f9f/6) added to question.

Comment: create a sqlfiddle and share the url. To me at least, I won't bother attempting queries without it. But that is just me.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f05f9f/6

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. Will look at when I get a chance. I modified the question so that should attract some people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement

select c_no,state,time from transactions inner join items on transactions.c_id=items.c_id where (state='Start' and right(time,8)<='17:00:00') or (state='Passed' and right(time,8)<='21:00:00')

Answer (score 0):

Ideas as follows:

```
with t_start as (
    select t2.c_no, t1.state, t1.time
    from transactions t1 
    inner join items t2 on t2.c_id=t1.c_id
    where t1.state='State' and time(t1.time)<='17:00:00'
) t_passed as(
    select t2.c_no, t1.state, t1.time
    from transactions t1 
    inner join items t2 on t2.c_id=t1.c_id
    where t1.state='Passed' and time(t1.time)<='21:00:00'
) t_total as(
    select * from t_start
    union
    select * from t_passed
)
select * from t_total order by c_no, state;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question, with your sample data, I don't think `C1` should exist in the result, because when `C_ID` = 5, and its `State` is 'Passed' and its `Time` is  '2016-07-07 21:04:01', it does not match your condition. So try this:

```
select t2.C_No, t.`State`, t.`Time`
from Transactions t
join (
    select C_ID
    from Transactions
    where (State = 'Start' and time(`Time`) <= '17:00:00')
    or (State = 'Passed' and time(`Time`) <= '21:00:00')
    group by C_ID
    having count(distinct State) > 1
) t1 on t.C_ID = t1.C_ID
left join Items t2 on t1.C_ID = t2.C_ID
order by t2.C_No, t.`State`;
```

[<kbd>SqlFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f05f9f/6)